# how to speed up the process of the ffmpeg command

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want use the overlay filter to composite the video with some image,

Command is `ffmpeg -i 30.mp4 -i out1.png -i out2.png -strict -2 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=enable='between(t,0,1)' [out]; [out][2:v] overlay=enable='between(t,2,3)'" -acodec copy -y -preset ultrafast output.mp4`

But the process need much time, I saw the process log below, i only overlay the frame between [0,1] and [2,3], but still need much time after the overlay time, the time consumed depends on the duration of the video but not the overlay time. Is is correct and why? And how can i speed up the process.

`03-13 17:02:29.388: D/FFmpegController(7445): out is frame=  113 fps= 21 q=30.0 size=     141kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 287.3kbits/s

03-13 17:02:29.905: D/FFmpegController(7445): out is frame=  130 fps= 22 q=31.0 size=     153kB time=00:00:04.01 bitrate= 312.5kbits/s

03-13 17:02:30.433: D/FFmpegController(7445): out is frame=  145 fps= 23 q=31.0 size=     160kB time=00:00:04.13 bitrate= 317.8kbits/s

03-13 17:02:30.917: D/FFmpegController(7445): out is frame=  148 fps= 21 q=29.0 size=     171kB time=00:00:05.05 bitrate= 276.8kbits/s

03-13 17:02:31.327: D/FFmpegController(7445): out is frame=  152 fps= 21 q=-1.0 Lsize=     196kB time=00:00:05.12 bitrate= 314.3kbits/s`

*Detail output of the command is here: http://tny.cz/d61fa88d*

Comment: How is the speed when you don't do the overlay?

Comment: @slhck it's slow than i expect，so i thought there're some common ways to speed up the command, or some notice i should not do in command. At least, some way to just speed up the overlay command.

Comment: Are you using a recent build of `ffmpeg`? Are you using the encoder `libx264` or the encoder `mpeg4`? Either can be default for MP4 output.  Is your linked x264 ancient? Is your build properly using CPU capabilities (it's not built with `--disable-yasm` is it)? Is your build appropriate for your system (such as, you're not using a 32-bit build or OS on a 64-bit capable system are you)? Some of these questions could be answered already if you would have provided the complete console output from your command which is basically required for `ffmpeg` questions.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard you'r right, i have add the output of the command.

Comment: `using cpu capabilities: none!`. That's not a good sign. Try a build that doesn't use `--disable-asm` (however I know nothing of Android CPU and what ASM has been done for those).

Comment: @LordNeckbeard  ok, i will check and try later. Any other suggestion will be appreciated.